# Uploads from site on Server A uploaded on Server B (Like sort of CDN)

Tags: uploads, cdn

Short overview of the situation: On server A there's an site. Server B is used for files. I want that uploads made on server A (running one wordpress site) are uploaded on server B.

I've changed the path to another server.
upload_path = uploads
upload_url_path = https://sub.domain/uploads

For some reason the URL is right, but the files aren't transferred. I checked the permissions of the folder and they are 777.

***Edit:***
After some checking I found in the root of my site (VPS A) the directory 'uploads' instead of on VPS B in the directory 'uploads' where it needs to be.

Comment: What options are set on server B? I can imagine that uploading from other servers is somewhat disabled by default - I wouldn't want anyone to upload lots of files to my server

Comment: What's the final goal you want to achieve? And what is your environment? Two dedicated servers under your control? Two shared webhosting packages? Something else? Generally, I wouldn't advise to do things like that unless you have a very good reason to and are aware of all the consequences.

Comment: The final goal is that all uploads are uploaded on server B. And at server A the site runs. It are 2 VPS. The main reason is speed improvement. A CDN isn't a solution, because we like control over the files and not a third-party.